# Remove index number from nested ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am trying to remove the index number from a nested column that has a ggplot figure when I compile with rmarkdown. I have tried changing the chunk options but I do not think the answer is there. I read that the `cat()` may work but unsure how to include.

Here is reprex:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(ggplot2)
    library(purrr)
    library(knitr)
    library(tinytex)

    knitr::opts_chunk$set( warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, comment = NA)

  df <- iris %>%  
         group_by(Species) %>%  
         nest() %>%  
         mutate(
             plot= purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()))

```

```{r}
   df %>% 
      filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
      select(plot) %>% 
      pull()
```
````

[image]

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `pluck` the `list` element

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
   ungroup %>%
   pull(plot) %>% 
   pluck(1)
```

Or it can be made more simpler with

```
df %>% 
   filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   pluck("plot", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly perfect.